# Corsair USB Flash Survivor Stealth USB 3.0 speeds not working in Ubuntu Linux 14.04.1 LTS (Recognizes as a USB 2.0 device)

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, usb-3

I'm finding that a Corsair USB Flash Survivor Stealth (USB 3.0 capable drive in Windows 7 with 200 MB/s Read speed) only connects at USB 2.0 speed in Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS).

Watching the /var/log/syslog I see that it recognizes as a "**high-speed**" device **instead of "SuperSpeed"**.   Maximum Read Speed benchmark shows 45 MB / sec (again, that is expected since it only recognizes it as a "high-speed" device.

Using the same port with **another USB 3.0 Flash Drive (Transcend JetFlash 790) it does actually recognize as a "SuperSpeed"** device and I get better than advertised read speeds (advertised 90 MB/s and I get over 100 MB/s).

The only other possible clue I might mention is I *think* the Corsair USB Flash Stealth Survivor uses a **Phison controller** (but I can't confirm that 100%).  The Transcend JetFlash 790 uses a **SMA controller** (Silicon Motion I believe; but again, I can't confirm that 100% either.. it's just what I read in various places).   That might have something to do with it?

Also, it's been suggested to load a different XHCI module;  however, I'm a little confused regarding this since I achieve proper USB 3.0 speeds and "SuperSpeed" recognition on every other USB 3.0 device I connect.

Anyone have any suggestions to get this drive to correctly recognize as a USB 3.0 "SuperSpeed" device?